# How to Zip GitLab current repo using gitlab-ci.yml and exclude some files

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to zip my repository and exclude some files from the zipped folder. I tried to implement a bash script for zipping. However, I was not succeed

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you tried and what the result was?